# How can i get user id's who are login with facebook credentials in to my android application

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In my application I am using login with facebook, if user clicks on button it shows facebook login screen, if user entered the credentials I would like to get the user id, here I am pasting `login()` code could you please tell me what are the changes I have to do for getting the user id?

```
private void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

            @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());

                        try {
                            editor.putString("access_expires",
                                    facebook.request("me"));

                            try {
                                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(facebook
                                        .request("me", values));
                                String userId = json.getString("id");

                            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Log.i(TAG, facebook.request("me"));
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error
                        Log.wtf(TAG, error);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors
                        Log.wtf(TAG, fberror);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an api call for user info of the current user, which will include their id:

https://graph.facebook.com/me

You can hit that url by calling:

```
facebook.request("me")
```

after authenticating.

It returns a json user object, which you can parse and get the id from:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: i am using facebook graph api

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me  link is not working , could you send me the correct one

Comment: What is the class of the facebook object?

Comment: private com.facebook.android.Facebook facebook;

Comment: Could you add a description of what's not working? The code seems fine as it is.